# How can I set nested array values in meteor publish function?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, set, publish, meteor

I have two collection "contents" and "units". In the content collection is a field "unitID" which refers to the unit-collection. In the meteor publish function I want to add the unit type name of all new created contents:

```
Meteor.publish("contents", function () {
  var self = this;

  var handle = Contents.find().observe({
    changed: function(contentdoc, contentid) {
        var UnitName = Units.findOne({_id: contentdoc.unittypeid }, {fields: {type: 1}});

        self.set("contents", contentid, {'content.0.typename': UnitName});
        self.flush();
    }
  });
}
```

This works but it creates a new attribut "content.0.UnitName" instead of inserting the attribute "UnitName" in the first element of the content array:

```
[
    {
       _id:"50bba3ca8f3d1db27f000021",
       'content.0.UnitName':
       {
           _id:"509ff643f3a6690c9ca5ee59",
           type:"Drawer small"
       },
       content:
       [
           {
               unitID:"509ff643f3a6690c9ca5ee59",
               name: 'Content1'
           }
       ]
    }
]
```

What I want is the following:

```
[
    {
       _id:"50bba3ca8f3d1db27f000021",          
       content:
       [
           {
               unitID:"509ff643f3a6690c9ca5ee59",
               name: 'Content1',
               UnitName:
               {
                    _id:"509ff643f3a6690c9ca5ee59",
                    type:"Drawer small"
                }
           }
       ]
    }
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.set` within `Meteor.publish` only works on the top-level properties of an object, meaning it doesn't support Mongo-style dotted attributes. You'll have to call `set` with the entire new value of the `contents` array.

Answer (score 4):

Caveat:  What I am about to say is going to change in a future release of Meteor.  We're currently overhauling the custom publisher API to make it easier to use, but in a way that breaks back-compatibility.

That said...

It looks like what you're trying to do is build a server-side join into the published collection "contents".  Here, for reference, is the current code (as of 0.5.2) that publishes a cursor (for when your publisher returns a cursor object):

```
Cursor.prototype._publishCursor = function (sub) {
  var self = this;
  var collection = self._cursorDescription.collectionName;

  var observeHandle = self._observeUnordered({
    added: function (obj) {
      sub.set(collection, obj._id, obj);
      sub.flush();
    },
    changed: function (obj, oldObj) {
      var set = {};
      _.each(obj, function (v, k) {
        if (!_.isEqual(v, oldObj[k]))
          set[k] = v;
      });
      sub.set(collection, obj._id, set);
      var deadKeys = _.difference(_.keys(oldObj), _.keys(obj));
      sub.unset(collection, obj._id, deadKeys);
      sub.flush();
    },
    removed: function (oldObj) {
      sub.unset(collection, oldObj._id, _.keys(oldObj));
      sub.flush();
    }
  });

  // _observeUnordered only returns after the initial added callbacks have run.
  // mark subscription as completed.
  sub.complete();
  sub.flush();

  // register stop callback (expects lambda w/ no args).
  sub.onStop(function () {observeHandle.stop();});
};
```

To build a custom publisher that is joined with another table, modify the added callback to:

- check if the added object has the key you want to join by
- do a find in the other collection for that key
- call set on your subscription with the new key and value you want to be published, before you call flush.

Note that the above is only sufficient if you know the key you want will always be in the other table, and that it never changes.  If it might change, you'll have to set up an observe on the second table too, and re-set the key on the sub in the changed method there.